# Adjust height of two ImageView with equal width according to screen height with ContraintLayout

Tags: android, imageview, height, width, android-constraintlayout

I want to implement a very simple view which I can do programatically, but I'd like to know if it can be done by using ConstraintLayout exclusively.

The structure is like this:

- ContraintLayout

  - ImageView1
  - ImageView2

One ImageView is in top of the other like in the following image:

[image: stacked images]

ImageView1 has a drawable with x1 height and w width.
ImageView2 has a drawable with x2 height and w width.

I would like to scale both drawables equally, maintaining their proportion and for Android to adjust the width to make the two views take the entire height of the container.

Right now, I'm doing it programatically after the view is layed out with the following function:

```
private int getWidthForHeight(int height) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getWidthForHeight: " + height);
    Drawable t = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_left_menu_mid_bg);
    int toh = t.getIntrinsicHeight();
    int tow = t.getIntrinsicWidth();
    Drawable b = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_left_menu_bottom_bg);
    int boh = b.getIntrinsicHeight();
    int bow = b.getIntrinsicWidth();

    // height = th + bh
    // (toh / tow) * w = th => w = (th * tow) / toh
    // (boh / bow) * w = bh => w = (bh * bow) / boh
    // (th * tow) / toh = (bh * bow) / boh => boh * th * tow = toh * bh * bow
    // boh * th * tow = toh * bh * bow => boh * th * tow = toh * (height - th) * bow
    // boh * th * tow = (toh * height - toh * th) * bow
    // boh * th * tow = bow * toh * height - bow * toh * th
    // th * (boh * tow + bow * toh) = bow * toh * height

    // th = (bow * toh * height) / (boh * tow + bow * toh)
    // bh = height - th

    float th = ((float) (bow * toh * height)) / ((float) (boh * tow + bow * toh));
    float bh = height - th;
    float width = (th * tow) / (float) toh;

    Log.d(TAG, "getWidthForHeight: th = " + th + ", bh = " + bh);
    Log.d(TAG, "getWidthForHeight: width = " + width);

    return Math.round(width);
}
```

This, however, seems a bit hacky to me, and I'm sure there's a simpler way to do it in Android. However, I haven't been able to find it.

Can somebody shine some light on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, *ImageView2* is twice the height of *ImageView1* and you would like that 2-1 ratio to hold regardless of screen orientation or device screen size.

Try using vertical weights with the *ImageViews* and a *layout_height* of `0dp` (*match_constraints*).

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*Portrait*

[image]

*Landscape*

[image]

Comment: The top one is not twice the height, but you were on the right track with the weights. I ended up setting the vertical weight of the top one to the original top.png height, and the vertical weight of the bottom one to the original bottom.png height. That way, android adjusts it accordingly and the view looks good :)